# memcached with telnet disabled

Tags: memcached

If telnet is disabled on my RHL server memcached gives the error of unable to connect to host: myMachine:port number when starting my java web app.

Is it mandatory to enable telnet for memcached to work? For security purpose if it has been disabled how does one enable it to work in a distributed env?. Are there any configurations for that.  What about the configurations that are required in the case of firewalls?.

Comment: What is the port number in "myMachine:port number"? Is this host:port combination anywhere in your Java source?

Answer (score 3):

Memcached has nothing to do with telnet. It uses TCP port 11211 by default, so make sure you accept connections to this port in your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the code is using telnet to check if the service is listening on the standard port for memcached.

Cheers